# Dagger-2 "lateinit property application has not been initialized"

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am trying to inject application context in a class which is giving

> ”lateinit property application has not been initialized"

exception.

CoreModule.kt

```
@Module
open class CoreModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRealmHelper(): RealmHelper {
        return RealmHelper()
    }
}

MyApplication.kt

open class MyApplication : MultiDexApplication(), HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass)!!

    companion object {
        var application: MyApplication? = null

        fun getInstance(): MyApplication {
            return application!!
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        try {
            super.onCreate()
            application = this
            DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build().inject(this)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            log.error("Exception in Application", e)
            Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(GlobalExceptionHandler())
        }

    }

    override fun activityInjector() = dispatchingAndroidInjector
}

AppComponent.kt

@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,CoreModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: MyApplication): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(myApplication: MyApplication)

    fun inject(realmHelper: RealmHelper)
}
```

//I need application context in this class. I am inject applicationContext here.
Is injecting is correct way to do or I should use constructor injection?

```
RealmHelper.kt

class RealmHelper @Inject constructor() {
//need application context here but getting "lateinit property application has not been initialized
    @Inject
    lateinit var application: MyApplication

   init {
        Realm.init(application) // null application
    }
}
```

Note: MyApplication is added to AndoridManifest.xml

Comment: Have you provide MyApplication class in AndroidManifest.xml -> android:name=".MySnaxApplication"???

Comment: yes, application class is added to AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you annotated your field but not injected. You can inject field like you did in application class : `DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build().inject(this)`

or you can move your application field to RealmHelper constructor and in core module you need to write a provide function to return application. If you want to see an example I have an applicaton. https://github.com/volkansahin45/Moneycim

Comment: DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build().inject(this) is added to application class.

Comment: Ok but you need to inject all activity fragment component etc where you inject something

Comment: activity and fragment class in injected. I have added AndroidInjection.inject(this) in activity and AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this) in fragment class

Comment: But you did not in RealmHelper

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for on so many stackoverflow threads and it was just a. simple thing I missed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

> I need application context in this class. I am inject
>   applicationContext here. Is injecting is correct way to do or I should
>   use constructor injection?

Always favor constructor injection over field injection if possible.

Your `CoreModule` is not needed. The code below is enough.

```
@Singleton
class RealmHelper @Inject constructor(private val application: MyApplication) {
//Your implementation 
}
```

`fun inject(realmHelper: RealmHelper)` in your Component is also unnecessary.

Removing those lines should fix it, I quickly threw together a demo project just to test it to make sure. [Here](https://gist.github.com/WhosNickDoglio/6b80fee66f5edb376d2f9038195dee78) is a quick gist with the code.

Answer (score 0):

this might be too late but this may help other developer..

```
@set:Inject
internal var activityDispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>? = null
```

use this instead of

```
@Inject
lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>
```

and in case you get same error elsewhere, do the same. Use **@set:Inject** instead of **@Inject** and use **internal** instead of **lateinit**.

This worked for me like charm.